# Stock Android for Samsung Note 2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms, samsung, stock-android

Where can I find stock Android for Samsung Galaxy Note 2?

Comment: Please see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 1):

A great place to start would be [on the ROM list for your device on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-2#romList).

There are many options available, so which one you want to install comes down to user preference.

Please note that it will be required that you root your device, so proceed with caution as your warranty will be void.

Your other alternative is building it yourself from source.

Comment: Yep ! I have gone through these forums ! But the problem is i am not able to find the stock android version . So i need a link to get that rom . :)

Comment: I don't think a completely "stock android" ROM is available for your device. You could build your own if you are capable?

Answer (score 0):

[**Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Also, if you like ***Lollipop***, i suggest you use Nameless Rom.

this Custom rom (Nameless) availabe on XDA :

[**[ROM][5.0.2][Lollipop][Official][Nightlies] NamelessROM 2.0**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-2/orig-development/rom-namelessrom-2-0-t2943424)

Download Link :

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/namelessrom/files/n-2.0/n7100/
> the best and faster Rom for now for Galaxy Note 2.

also for Stock Rom :

**`http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-N7100/`**

Comment: Yea sure i will try this rom !! But can you get me link for stock android rom ! I need it very badly :)

Comment: Edit And updated.please see `Sammobile` link in my answer.

Comment: NO the one you gave me is the samsung's version . I need pure android like one in nexus !

Comment: this is your question before edit : `Where can u find Stock Android for Samsung Note 2 . I Mean the google version which comes in Nexus , Motorolla .` is not possible or your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Also, means about `Stock`, it means, Rom only availabe for Note 2 from samsung comapany and it's `Stable` for use.